How to generate KML from JSON file?(color is not showing in KML)
I generated the KML but the color is not showing in KML file that I exported.
I used the tokml library and from 3 json file all of them is generating truely. what should I do to show the colors in exported file?
Is anything to use? I tryed the hextoRGB too, but it's not effective...
import tokml from "tokml";
    const handleDownloadKML = async () => {
        try {
          const layerToFileMap = {
            "City Borders": "city.json",
            "Province Borders": "province.json",
            "Municipality Border": "districts.json",
          };
    
          // Check if we can map the layer to a JSON file
          const fileName = layerToFileMap[layer.name];
    
          if (fileName) {
            // If a matching file is found, fetch from public folder
            const fileUrl = `${window.location.origin}/data/map/${fileName}`;
            const response = await fetch(fileUrl);
    
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error(`Failed to fetch JSON file. Status: ${response.status}`);
            }
    
            const jsonData = await response.json();
            
            // Convert the JSON (GeoJSON) to KML using tokml
            const kmlData = tokml(jsonData);
            
            // Create a Blob from the KML data
            const blob = new Blob([kmlData], {
              type: "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml",
            });

this is one of my json example file that U can see the color in properties: but is shows White all the coordinates that I have. enter image description here


{     "type": "FeatureCollection",     "features": [         {             "type": "Feature",             "properties": {                 "ProvinceName": "SOMEWHERE",                 "color": "#7d3041",                 "opacity": 0.5             },             "geometry": {                 "type": "Polygon",                 "coordinates": [                     [                         [                             50.49594280000008,                             36.34221420000006                         ],                         [                             50.50149950000008,                             36.34166460000006                         ],


Did you try to enter the color code without the double quotes ?
